# Adding views until there is no more room

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build a RPN Calculator

[image]

The keyboard shrinks and stretches quite well, so I would like to add stack rows to the view (blue selection)

```
3:      0
2:      0 
1:      0
```

Until there is no more room on the screen/view.

The xml for the first row, and its container is.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/stackLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!--  Stack row -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stackRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        >
        <!--  Row index -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1:"
            style="@style/text_style" />
        <!-- Value -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="0"
            style="@style/text_style" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My failed attempt at trying to add elements is in the activitys onCreate

```
// Setup table rows for value stack
LinearLayout stackView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stackLayout);
int heightPx = stackView.getHeight();
LinearLayout stackRow = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stackRow);
int rowHeightPx = stackRow.getHeight();
// Space for additional rows
int heightLeftPx = heightPx - rowHeightPx;

//stackView.removeView(stackRow);
// Add rows to fit
int count = 0;
while (heightLeftPx > rowHeightPx) {
    count++;
    // add new LinearLayout row
    heightLeftPx-= rowHeightPx;
}
```

The stackView keeps reporting its height as 0. As does the row. 
Where am I going wrong?

I have tried moving this to onStart, onResume and onPostResume with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add to my Activity onCreate:

```
new AnInnerSillyWaitToCompleteLayoutClass().execute((Void[]) null);
```

Then in my Activity I had an:

```
class AnInnerSillyWaitToCompleteLayoutClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
         sleep a little while

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         Here the layout is complete and the dynamic
         dimensions can be calculated.
```

Edit: The proper way is to listen for layout changes, and implement these action after the layout is complete.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the views aren't rendered yet in oncreate? Maybe in on resume they are?

Comment: They yield 0 in OnCreate, OnStart and OnResume.